# Having issue with a very simple java program, not displaying proper result

Tags: java, printf, double, java.util.scanner

here is my code that isn't working:

```
Scanner hello = new Scanner (System.in);
double a = 10;
double c;

System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
c = hello.nextDouble();
double f = a + c;
System.out.printf("The sum of 10 plus user entry is : ", a+c);
```

No syntax error whatsoever, no error displayed, this is the result :
     Enter the value: 100
     The sum of 10 plus user entry is :

So there is no result in the second line,,, for the command ( a+c ) as in program. But if i use a ' %.2f ' before ( a+c ) command, it works fine,,
like :

```
System.out.printf("The sum of 10 plus user entry is : %.2f", a+c);
```

I tried to search about the '%.2f' but got to know it is used just to ascertain that the following number is to be displayed as a number with two decimal places. (kinda round off thing, i guess)..

I'm totally a rookie at Java. Started studying it at college right now. Was just curious to know about this concept and reason behind why this program worked only with the '%.2f' typed in it, and not without it, although it showed no error. Will be great if someone can answer it. thanks :-)

Comment: In the first example, `printf` requires an appropriate "%" in the string or it doesn't print anything.  You're not seeing any output because you told it not to print anything.

Comment: But i don't generally use a "%" in    printf, every time I print something using    printf , ex:    printf("I'm just a beginner")    it works well without a "%". Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `System.out.printf()` method doesn't append information; it substitutes it. The '%.2f' means: "Replace this with the next argument, and convert it to a floating-point number 2 places precise." Removing the '%.2f' would mean that `a+c` would have nowhere to go, and `printf()` would discard it.

Since Java's `System.out.printf()` method is actually based on the `printf()` from C/C++, you might want to check out [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) guide.

Comment: Thanks a lot. for the time i just used '+' operator and a new variable for the value of 'a+c';  so that j = a+c;    and used a '+' instead of comma.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function.
You should be using

```
System.out.println(myString)
```

Or

```
System.out.print(myString)
```

You would format your code as

```
System.out.println(myExplinationString + a+c)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just curious to know about 'printf' and how it was working here. anyways thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is an instance of [`java.io.PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) class that is provided as a static field of the [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class. `printf(String format, Object... args)` is one of the methods of the `PrintStream` class, check this [Oracle tutorial on formatting numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html). In brief, the first argument is a format string that may contain plain text and format specifiers, e.g. `%.2f`, that are applied to the next argument(s). All format specifiers are explained in the description of the [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class. Note, that `double` value is [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) to `Double`.